# Apache mod_rewrite REQUEST_URI not matching pattern

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

Apache 2.4 on CentOS 7, on a cPanel/WHM remote server.

I want to get the Apache server's 404 response when a .jpg file is not found, instead of Rewriting to index.php which loads the entire web app.

Trying to do this in `.htaccess`.

```
#Trying to exclude jpegs:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpg$
#And exclude these folders:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(folder1|folder2)/
#And rewrite everything else (commenting this results in regular Apache 404 responses for missing image files):
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

When I try to load these URLs that result in `404`, `example.com/asdf.jpg`, or `example.com/folder1/abc.css`, the `RewriteRule` still goes into effect, they get rewritten to `index.php`, and the CMS `404` page gets loaded.

When I comment the `RewriteRule`, then those two urls result in the lightweight Apache `404` response instead of the CMS `404` response.

Complete `mod_rewrite` section of `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

        RewriteBase /


    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(folder1|folder2)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
## test excluding .jpg from rewrite
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.jpg)$

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Edit - here is the `VirtualHost` config:

```
<VirtualHost 12.34.56.7:80>
  ServerName site.example.com
  ServerAlias www.site.example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/someuser/public_html
  ServerAdmin webmaster@site.example.com
  UseCanonicalName Off
  CustomLog /etc/apache2/logs/domlogs/site.example.com combined
  <IfModule log_config_module>
    <IfModule logio_module>
      CustomLog /etc/apache2/logs/domlogs/site.example.com-bytes_log "%{%
s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  ## User someuser # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
  <IfModule userdir_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_itk.c>
      <IfModule !ruid2_module>
        UserDir enabled someuser
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Enable backwards compatible Server Side Include expression parser for Apache
 versions >= 2.4.
  # To selectively use the newer Apache 2.4 expression parser, disable SSILegacy
ExprParser in
  # the user's .htaccess file.  For more information, please read:
  #    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#ssilegacyexprparser
  <IfModule include_module>
    <Directory "/home/someuser/public_html">
      SSILegacyExprParser On
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule suphp_module>
    suPHP_UserGroup someuser someuser
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule suexec_module>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
      SuexecUserGroup someuser someuser
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule ruid2_module>
    RMode config
    RUidGid someuser someuser
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mpm_itk.c>
    # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
    #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
    AssignUserID someuser someuser
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/someuser/public_html/cgi-bin/
  </IfModule>

  # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
  # Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/someuser/csite.example.com/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit, I did rewrite `trace6`. It shows the `.*` rule being applied even though `folder1` should not get the rule applied. I tried this on a virtual machine testing server and it works there, but not on this physical remote server.

Here are the first 13 lines of the trace:

```
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389721 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f002b310/initial] [perdir /home/someuser/public_html/] add path info postfix: /home/someuser/public_html/folder1/catalog/ABC -> /home/someuser/public_html/folder1/catalog/ABC/10162015/Asdf.jpg, referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389764 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f002b310/initial] [perdir /home/someuser/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/someuser/public_html/folder1/catalog/ABC/10162015/Asdf.jpg -> folder1/catalog/ABC/10162015/Asdf.jpg, referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389775 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f002b310/initial] [perdir /home/someuser/public_html/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'folder1/catalog/ABC/10162015/Asdf.jpg', referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389790 2016] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f002b310/initial] setting env variable'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' to '', referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389802 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f002b310/initial] [perdir /home/someuser/public_html/] add path info postfix: /home/someuser/public_html/folder1/catalog/ABC -> /home/someuser/public_html/folder1/catalog/ABC/10162015/Asdf.jpg, referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389812 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f002b310/initial] [perdir /home/someuser/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/someuser/public_html/folder1/catalog/ABC/10162015/Asdf.jpg -> folder1/catalog/ABC/10162015/Asdf.jpg, referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389821 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f002b310/initial] [perdir /home/someuser/public_html/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'folder1/catalog/ABC/10162015/Asdf.jpg', referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389835 2016] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f002b310/initial] [perdir /home/someuser/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/folder1/catalog/ABC/10162015/Asdf.jpg' pattern='!^/(folder1|folder2)/' => not-matched, referer:http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389844 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f002b310/initial] [perdir /home/someuser/public_html/] pass through /home/someuser/public_html/folder1/catalog/ABC, referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389922 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f001bae8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/someuser/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/someuser/public_html/404.shtml -> 404.shtml, referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389945 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f001bae8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/someuser/public_html/] applying pattern '.*' to uri '404.shtml', referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389958 2016] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f001bae8/initial/redir#1] setting env variable 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' to '', referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
[Fri Nov 11 02:21:08.389969 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25637:tid 139651102975744] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 45.67.87.76:57196] 45.67.87.76 - - [site.example.com/sid#7f031c7731e0][rid#7f02f001bae8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/someuser/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/someuser/public_html/404.shtml -> 404.shtml, referer: http://site.example.com/widgets/bathroom/
```

Comment: Are there any other rules above/below these?

Comment: The whole thing is enclosed in an `if module` for `mod_rewrite` and then the only thing before the directives in my question is related to http/https which doesn't seem like it would affect this problem. Afterwards there is nothing.

Comment: Your rules look OK, and I even tried to reproduce the issue on my server, but it all works as you would expect. Check for types, browser caching, and enable rewrite trace logging.

Comment: @anubhava but shouldn't the previous `RewriteCond` prevent the `.*` from applying to the files I want to exclude? Also, isn't your rewrite rule completely useless, since it just rewrites `index.php` to itself? `ewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]` ????

Comment: @anubhava I'm sorry I missed the `!` but it still does not fix the issue. `.jpg` is still rewriting to `index.php`, triggering CMS response. Also, is there really any difference between `.*` and `!^index\.php$`? Not much, right? And since the point is *not* to rewrite `.jpg` (and some other) files, that regex really makes no difference, right?

Comment: @DusanBajic I have just posted the full Rewrite section of my `.htaccess`. It all looks good?

Comment: @anubhava no `.htaccess` above it, and below it only `deny from all` for some directories. There is also system-wide config but it would not have any rewrite rules in it.

Comment: Can you share the virtualhost config?

Comment: Also what is your Apache version?

Comment: @DusanBajic I added the `VirtualHost` config. @anubhava, it's Apache 2.4.

Comment: @DusanBajic I tried this on a local virtual machine and it works. But not on the remote physical server. I posted the first 13 of 115 lines from the rewrite trace. Can ou see any clues from that?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your rule is catching the subrequest when looking for the matching `ErrorDocument`. Try adding the `NS` flag to your rule.

Comment: I changed the rule to this, but the result is the same as before. `RewriteRule .* index.php [L,NS]`

Comment: If you don't have `ErrorDocument`s set, Apache can get an internal 404 on them, so it may be that your rules are catching that somehow. You have access to server config, so [use logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) at `trace8` to see what's going on.

Comment: I posted the first 13 lines of the 115 line `trace6`. Can you tell anything from that or should I post more of it (or all of it)?

Comment: The `.jpg` is irrelevant for that URL, it starts with `/folder1/`, which excludes it from the `RewriteRule`, so that's where it's trying to go. Of course `.*` matches, it'll match anything, but that doesn't mean the rule is *applied*, the `RewriteCond`s stop it. It looks like you have something somewhere in `folder1` that's doing more rewriting or aliasing, possibly with the `PT` flag as lines 8 & 9 of that log section indicate.

Comment: Your idea that there might be an `.htaccess` inside of `/folder1/` was a good one but I checked and there was none. But it got me thinking, and I did a `grep -lr "404" .` in apache's configuration folder. I found a file called `errordocument.conf` that has this line `ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml`. So when Apache fails to find the `.jpg` file it generates a 404 and immediately looks for a `404.shtml` in my site's root. I don't have one, so now (I'm guessing) that generates another 404? And since `/404.shtml` does not match any of my rules, it gets rewritten to `index.php`

Comment: That's what I meant with my first comment.

Comment: Oh yeah! I think that comment was also still bouncing around in my mind. But why doesn't the trace tell you which file is effecting changes on the rewritten URL?

Comment: And my answer. I guess I was too brief.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't? Perhaps because you used `trace6` not `trace8`?

Comment: Well the NS flag didn't work for some reason, but you were definitely on the right track. I will try 'trace8'. It's pretty hard to follow 115 lines of output for just a single image resource request, though. I wish there was an easier way.

Comment: If you have that many lines you may be doing something wrong. Keep the `NS` flag as that rule need only be applied to the initial user request.